# Unable to retrieve data from catalog using WhatsApp Cloud API

Tags: whatsapp

I'm unable to send multiproduct messages to users. Every time I send the request I receive the same error. The following attachment shows the catalog connected to the number.

[image]

The body of the request:

```
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "to": "###########",
  "type": "interactive",
  "interactive": {
    "type": "product_list",
    "header": {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "text-header-content"
    },
    "body": {
      "text": "text-body-content"
    },
    "footer": {
      "text": "text-footer-content"
    },
    "action": {
      "catalog_id": "673529427462715",
      "sections": [
        {
          "title": "the-section-title",
          "product_items": [
            {
              "product_retailer_id": "K456653445"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The error received:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#131009) Parameter value is not valid",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 131009,
    "error_data": {
      "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
      "details": "None of the products provided could be sent. Please check your catalog."
    },
    "error_subcode": 2494010,
    "fbtrace_id": "A4YbEq8SQ7rMIisuc4M2HiX"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we are also stuck on this issue no one having any idea how we can resolve this issue.

we had contacted the meta for this and getting in reply that **there is no catalogue linked to facebook business manager**.

> - Please check your fb manager if catalogue is not linked then link your catalogue and give a try.

There is some issue in Facebook business manager as per there reply, still finding the solution for this. if we found any solution will let you know

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I realized it was caused by broken image urls. Fixing the image urls fixed the problem.